# How to get Categories in which user is interested Facebook Graph API?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am using the Facebook Graph API.

`FBGraphApi: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=AAAC8i7Jj25kBALQ....`

and get following in response:

```
{   "data": [
  {
     "category": "Media/news/publishing",
     "category_list": [
        {
           "id": "191684877517919",
           "name": "Publisher"
        },
        {
           "id": "108366235907857",
           "name": "Newspaper"
        }
     ],
     "name": "YTPO.Ru",
     "id": "157031727688210",
     "created_time": "2013-04-09T16:09:44+0000"
  },,
  {
     "category": "Education website",
     "name": "Afla.md",
     "id": "243281895771734",
     "created_time": "2012-09-15T13:20:03+0000"
  },
  {
     "category": "Website",
     "name": "Forbes Russia",
     "id": "315590990710",
     "created_time": "2012-08-01T20:25:18+0000"
  },
  {
     "category": "Non-governmental organization (ngo)",
     "name": "Alliance Fran\u00e7aise de Moldavie",
     "id": "177432232301977",
     "created_time": "2012-02-23T16:10:17+0000"
  }   ],
```

I need categories in which the user is interested. How can I get these category in other languages, for example French or German?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if we will add in the end https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=AAAC8i7Jj25kBALQ......&locale=fr then the data came in france